# Trouble getting program to run on putty when converting string to int array

Tags: c++

```
int H[500]; // global int array
int main()
{
    int check[500];
    bool same = true;
    string input;
    cout << "Enter Numbers: ";
    getline(cin, input);
    istringstream buf(input);
    istream_iterator<string> beg(buf), end;
    vector<string> tokens(beg, end);
    int temp = 1;
    for (auto& s : tokens)  // error: expected initializer before ‘:’ token
    {
        H[temp] = atoi(s.c_str());
        check[temp] = atoi(s.c_str());
        temp++;
    } 
    for (int ii = 1; ii < temp; ii++)
        heapsort(temp);//cpp:43: error: expected primary-expression before ‘for’
                      //         error: expected ‘;’ before ‘for’
                      //         error: expected primary-expression before ‘for’
                      //         error: expected ‘)’ before ‘for’

    return 0;
}
```

I get these errors when I attempt to compile this on putty. It works fine on visual studio. I appreciate any help I can get. Thank you.

EDIT:
I use "g++ -0 filename filename.cpp" when im on putty.

Comment: As far as I know, putty is not a compiler. What compiler are you using? Which flags do you use to compile?

Comment: you probably miss `-std=c++11`

Comment: I suppose you write (or want to write) `-o` instead of `-0` in your `g++` command invocation?

Comment: Please post the output of `g++ --version` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Putty` is not a compiler but a terminal, so I'll assume that by putty you mean some remote Linux or Unix with `g++` or `clang++` on it. I will also assume that you have all the necessary includes and and namespace directives, like `using namespace std;` statement in place since you said that you've compiled this code successfully elsewhere.

I think your problem is that you need to add `-std=c++11` to the compiler arguments.

Also I'd use `strtol` or even better `stringstream` instead of `atoi`, since there is no way to check for errors when `atoi` is used so you will end up with a bunch of zeroes in your vector in case the input is not correct.

Comment: When I try to add the argument "g++ -std=c++11 -o filename filename.cpp"
I get this error: "cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"" I got the stringstream to work though thank you for that. Anyways when the professor is grading this hes not going to use the "--std=c++11" argument so I have to get it to work without that. I think the problem is with the for statement. Do you know a way that I can get it to run all the way through the stringstream and break the loop when it's out of integers?

Comment: @BStill: what version of g++ have you got there? (g++ -v)

Comment: @BStill Try `--std=c++11`. Note two minus signs.

Comment: @Sergey: one dash is legit as well. I reckon the compiler is pre-C++11.

Comment: How do I check the version? I tried with both one dash and two dashes and still the same error

Comment: @BStill: g++ --version OR g++ -v

Comment: g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)

Comment: @BStill: yip, your compiler is too old. You can modify the for loop to pre-C++11 using iterates or upgrade the compiler.